# Is there a bijective correspondence among the sets $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K \supset \mathbb{Q}_p$ be the $p$-adic field and let $O_K$ be its ring of integers and $M_K$ be the maximal ideal with integral closure $\bar{M}_K$. Consider a power series $f(x) \in O_K[[x]]$ without *constant term*. Now consider the following two sets (for fixed $n$):
\begin{align*}
 A_n&=\{x \in \bar{M}_K ~|~ f^n(x)=0 \ \text{and} \ f^{n-1}(x) \neq 0, \ n \geq 1 \}, \\
 B_{n,m}&=\{x \in \bar{M}_K ~|~ f^n(x)=f^m(x), \ \text{where} \ n>m \geq 0 \},\\
 C_n&=\{x \in \bar{M}_K ~|~ f^n(x)=f^{n-1}(x) \}.
\end{align*}
Here $f^n=f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f$ ($n$ times) is the iteration of $f$.

In fact, $A$ is the set of Torsion points of $f$ of exactly $n$-th iteration while $B$ is the set preperiodic points of $f$.

**My question:**

$(1)$ when is there a bijective correspondence between the sets $A_n$ and $B_{n,m}$ on some condition of $m$?

$(2)$ Is there a bijective correspondence between the sets $A_n$ and $C_n$ ?

Comment: The dependence on $n,m$ is not clear to me. You say that $A$ is the set of periodic points of $f$ of exactly $n$-th iteration, so $A$ depends on $n$ right ? You say that $B$ is the set of preperiodic points, so it does not depends neither on $n$, nor on $m$, is this what is intended ? What about $C$ ?

Comment: Beside this clarification, have you thought about the case where $f$ is the multiplication by a $n$-th root of unity ? $f$ is bijective with only one fixed point so $C=\{0\}$ while $A=\overline{M}_K$.

Comment: @Roland, why $B$ doesn'tdepend on $n$ and $m$? If you change $n$ and $m$,there will be different preperiodic points. Second, $C$ is itself a set. I need to relate these $3$ sets

Comment: Well, if you say that $B$ is the set of preperiodic points, then $B$ does not depends on $n$, nor on $m$ : $B=\{x~|~ \exists n\neq m\in\mathbb{N}, f^n(x)=f^m(x)\}$. But you actually mean $B_{n,m}$ with fixed $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ right ? This is not clear from the formulation.

Comment: @Roland, Sorry. I had some mistake in the question. The set $A$ is set of torsion points. Please see the edited question

Comment: @Roland, yes you are right that $n, m$ are fixed in $A$ and $B$ and $C$.